# VBA - Deleting Rows When All Columns are 0

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone please tell me how to write the VBA code to delete all rows when all of the data in columns C-M are 0. If there is anything in any of the columns other then 0 I need the row to stay.

All of the information I am finding shows how to delete a row but only based on 1 column.

The files this will be used on can range anywhere from 5 rows to 1500 rows.

Comment: `Range.AutoFilter` - with a filter on each field for 0? And then delete visible cells?

Comment: When you say "other then 0" do you mean only numbers? What about blank cells and text lines? Consider them as zero?

Comment: There will be no blank cells either a number or just 0.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to what BigBen suggested.  Assume we have m rows of data, then:

1. Read the m by C-M block of cells as a 2D array (matrix)
2. Sum each row of the matrix, if its zero then that row needs to be deleted
3. Delete rows from the spreadsheet starting from the bottom (i.e. with row m)

This last step is important, if you start from the top when deleting rows you'll end up skipping some.  For example, if you delete row 5, then what was row 6 becomes row 5 and when you move to the next row you've skipped what was originally row 6 because all of the rows have shifted up by one.

From a performance perspective BigBens comment is probably faster.  If you'll never exceed 1500 rows in your workbook, then this approach should be pretty quick as well.

Comment: A little clarification to point 2: sum the ABS() of each value. In the case of `0; -2; 0; -1; 0; 1; 2; 0` or something similar, you will throw away the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
for rw=1 to 1500          'loop through your rows
     'test if columns are empty
    if application.worksheetfunction.counta(range(cells(rw,3),cells(rw,13)))=0 then  
       Cells(rw, 1).EntireRow.Delete   'delete row of empty columns
    endif
next rw
```

Comment: Nice try. But are you sure that `CountA()` will actually check for "the data in columns C-M are 0"? In addition, when deleting elements of collections (in this case, row from rows), you must move in reverse order, otherwise you will miss some elements due to the shift of elements within the collection after deletion - `For rw = 1500 To 1 Step -1`

Comment: JohnSUN ,Missed that. we're looking for 0, instead of blanks  Saw your answer,I agree.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you will have column A as the main column with data for all records, please try below code if that works for you:

```
    Sub checkrows()
Range("A2").Select
While ActiveCell <> ""
c = 3
i = 0
For c = 3 To 13
r = ActiveCell.Row
If Cells(r, c).Value = "" Then i = i + 1
Next
If i = 11 Then
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
End If
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Would it be possible for showing a sample data table from columns A to M?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your question is **"Delete each row where cells in certain columns are zero"**

A simple way to check a cell for 0:

```
=(C2 <> 0)
```

The same for the range

```
{=(C2:M2 <> 0)}
```

This will return an array of values ​​like
`{FALSE\FALSE\TRUE\FALSE\...\FALSE\TRUE\FALSE\FALSE}`

It is enough for us to know the sum of this array: if it is greater than zero, then the range contains cells other than zero. Convert Boolean values ​​TRUE\FALSE to 1\0 using the [N()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/n-function-a624cad1-3635-4208-b54a-29733d1278c9) function and sum using the usual [SUM()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sum-function-043e1c7d-7726-4e80-8f32-07b23e057f89)

```
=SUM(N(C2:M2<>0))
```

This will work well with numbers and empty cells. But cells with texts from the point of view of Excel are not equal to zero. How do we know how many text cells are in our range?

```
=COUNTA(C2:M2)-COUNT(C2:M2)
```

We need to subtract this amount from our sum

```
=SUM(N(C2:M2<>0))-COUNTA(C2:M2)+COUNT(C2:M2)
```

How to use this formula in VBA macro code? With [Evaluate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate):

```
Sub removeZeroRows()
Dim rData As Range
Dim sRange As String
Dim i As Long
    Set rData = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = rData.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        sRange = Application.Intersect(rData.Rows(i), ActiveSheet.Columns("C:M")).Address
        If (Evaluate("=SUM(N(" & sRange & "<>0))-COUNTA(" & sRange & ")+COUNT(" & sRange & ")") = 0) Then rData.Rows(i).Delete
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```